# Datatables with column filter dropdowns and multiple checkbox selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, datatables

I found this excellent code from joao vitor retamero -  fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvretamero/bv6g0r64/  that shows how to make multiple selections in jquery datatable column filters. But I need to transform the filter containers into dropdowns, with each item in the container being a checkbox.  Yes, there are many references to this, as I've found out during several hours of researching.  But I'm yet to find any examples, or any clear explanations of how to do this, despite many saying it's possible with jquery plugin.  Can anyone point to any examples?  I've no clue how to even start.  Many thanks.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function (index, element) {
                            return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
                        }).toArray().join('|');

                        column
                            .search( vals.length > 0 ? '^('+vals+')$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this, which doesn't use any extra JS/jQuery libraries:

```
// This code has been beautified via http://jsbeautifier.org/ with 2 spaces indentation.
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cbDropdown(column) {
    return $('<ul>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown'
    }).appendTo($('<div>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown-wrap'
    }).appendTo(column));
  }

  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header()))
          .on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
            var active;
            var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
              active = true;
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();

            // Highlight the current item if selected.
            if (this.checked) {
              $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            } else {
              $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            }

            // Highlight the current filter if selected.
            var active2 = ddmenu.parent().is('.active');
            if (active && !active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().addClass('active');
            } else if (!active && active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().removeClass('active');
            }
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          var // wrapped
            $label = $('<label>'),
            $text = $('<span>', {
              text: d
            }),
            $cb = $('<input>', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              value: d
            });

          $text.appendTo($label);
          $cb.appendTo($label);

          ddmenu.append($('<li>').append($label));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* Styles for the drop-down. Feel free to change the styles to suit your website. :-) */

.cb-dropdown-wrap {
  max-height: 80px; /* At most, around 3/4 visible items. */
  position: relative;
  height: 19px;
}

.cb-dropdown,
.cb-dropdown li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.cb-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

/* For selected filter. */
.active .cb-dropdown {
  background: pink;
}

.cb-dropdown-wrap:hover .cb-dropdown {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: 0.2s height ease-in-out;
}

/* For selected items. */
.cb-dropdown li.active {
  background: #ff0;
}

.cb-dropdown li label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 19px; /* Match height of .cb-dropdown-wrap */
}

.cb-dropdown li label > input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 16px;
}

.cb-dropdown li label > span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 20px; /* At least, width of the checkbox. */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

/* This fixes the vertical aligning of the sorting icon. */
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-position: 100% 10px;
}
```

**Demo**

<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/1/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/6/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/8/</strike>
<strike>https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/9/</strike>
https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/10/

**UPDATE**

I moved the filter dropdowns to the header, and styled the dropdowns to look more like dropdown menus. (*No JS or jQuery involved in the dropdown functionality*; just pure CSS with basic animation — CSS3 `transition`.)

**UPDATE #2**

Sorry, I forgot apply the CSS "active" `class` to selected items.

**UPDATE #3**

Same like *Update #2* case, but for the dropdown menu wrapper. (Sorry for keep forgetting things.. and I edited just to conform/meet to the requirements/changes you've actually requested. :) <strike>But I think this update would be the final revision.</strike>)

**UPDATE #4**

Fixed the "active" *state change* of the dropdown menu wrapper.

**CREDITS**

Thank you @Giacomo for your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8Lozex7/3/). =)

Comment: Wow @sally-cj, that's impressive.  The only thing left now is for the container to to work as a dropdown.  You see I'll be putting the filters in the header, so I need them to contract when the filter is not in use.  Is this possible with CSS alone?

Comment: @Silverburch So you would like the container to expand on click?You can use CSS alone if you want expand on hover.
Anyway, how will the user notice what filters are "active"?
Will the user need to click/hover container and check one by one checked checkboxes?

Comment: Yes, expansion on hover would be fine. What would be great is if the dropdown box (when not expanded) could be a different colour if any of its options are ticked.  That would be enough to tell the user that selections have been made.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes if course, let me contribute on Sally CJ fiddle.

Comment: While waiting for @Sally CJ to review my edit on his answer, here is a link to fiddle with my contribution:
https://jsfiddle.net/xu58j5vh/7/

Comment: Well done Giacomo.  Perhaps could be made even smoother by moving the dropdowns to the header area ('header' in line 16 of fiddle) and in .cb-dropdown-wrap adding position: absolute, z-index = 1, and adjusting the background and top.  I'll give until tomorrow to give Sally CJ a chance to come back  before marking as the accepted answer.  This was a tough one.  Your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sally CJ Edited again, here is again a link to fiddle with my contribution:
https://jsfiddle.net/w8Lozex7/2/

Comment: Great, but how do I mark your fiddle as the accepted answer?  I can't award the bounty to it.  Do you need to restate the code?

Comment: Thanks @GiacomoPenuti for the edit. I'll check it out later. =)

Comment: @Silverburch I've updated my answer and also the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/41vgefnf/6/ Check it out and let me know if you need further changes.

Comment: Thanks @Sally CJ but there's still something not quite right with the dropdown colors.  If you tick 2 options, then untick just one, the colour should still be shown.  Instead it goes back to white.

Comment: That is perfect!

Comment: @SallyCJ A small bug : when the user click on a checkbox the sort event should be avoided. Here is a fix https://jsfiddle.net/cse12fq3/ .  Thanks for your work.

Comment: Man I need this code somehow :( but can't start because I am so confused in the JS part.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are searching for in user interface terms is a multiselect.

It doesn't actually exist a dropdown element with multiple selection using a checkbox (multiselect already exists for that kind of interaction need).

I think you need a custom multiselect with better user experience (not the default one like in example provided).

Here is a fiddle with my purpose, i understand that this is not exactly what you were asking for, but i pretty think this will suite your request at a more abstract level.

All i did is to use a jquery plugin called select2, very usefull to enhance ux and ui in various input elements.

Please check code comments for technicalities.

https://jsfiddle.net/p1261jby/3/

```
/*added as resources
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        //added class "mymsel"
        var select = $('<select class="mymsel" multiple="multiple"><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
      //select2 init for .mymsel class
      $(".mymsel").select2();
    }
  });
});
```

Here are Select2 docs in case you need to customize some parameters.
https://select2.org/selections

Comment: Hey @Giacomo-Penuti.  Thanks for responding. Technically I agree that using select2 works.  The problem is that its operation and the way it looks is clunky and I'm under strict instructions to provide a 'very smooth' user experience using checkboxes on a dropdown.  Is there an alternative custom multiselect that does use checkboxes instead?

Comment: You're wellcome. There is something i sometimes have to say to my clients and collegues: "What's wrost that reinvent the whell?Reinvent a square whell". I think that this exactly fits as what you are required to do. Select2 multiselect performance is fine. If it looks clunky and you want to improve ux, you can still work with some css and js for animation and better look.

Comment: If my 2 cents can't persuade you and your colleagues, please tell me and I will try to find a solution for that "checkboxes in dropdown" that theorically i think as checkboxes in a cosmetic dropdown or as a multiselect where options looks cosmetically like a checkbox.

Comment: I'm afraid they're really after checkbox dropdowns!  All because of the number of clicks required to make multiple selections in one filter

Answer (score 3):

Here's another flavour. It's using modified code from [Elmahdi Mahmoud](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri) for the multi-select, so I've left in his MIT copyright message.

I'll warn you now, the code isn't pretty, but the result is effective, so I thought it worth adding to the pile of options. A live fiddle is [here](http://live.datatables.net/wiyoredo/1/edit).

The JS is

```
    /* Plugin API method to determine is a column is sortable */
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('column().searchable()', function() {
  var ctx = this.context[0];
  return ctx.aoColumns[this[0]].bSearchable;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: true,
    pageLength: 25,
    orderCellsTop: true,
    columnDefs: [{
      searchable: false,
      targets: [0, 4]
    }],
  });

  // Add filtering
  table.columns().every(function() {
    if (this.searchable()) {
      var that = this;


      var myList = $('<ul/>');
      var myMulti = $('<div class="mutliSelect"/>');
      myList.appendTo(myMulti);

      var myDd = $('<dd/>');
      myMulti.appendTo(myDd);

      var myDropdown = $('<dl class="dropdown"/>');
      myDropdown.append('<dt><a href="#"><span class="hida">Select</span><p class="multiSel"></p></a></dt>');
      myDd.appendTo(myDropdown);

      myDropdown
        .appendTo(
          $('thead tr:eq(1) td').eq(this.index())
        )
        .on('change', function() {
          var vals = $(':checked', this).map(function(index, element) {
            return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
          }).toArray().join('|');

          that
            .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });


      // Add data
      this
        .data()
        .sort()
        .unique()
        .each(function(d) {
          myList.append($('<li><input type="checkbox" value="' + d + '"/>' + d + '</option>'));
        });

    }
  });


  /*
    Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
    (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
    license: https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  */

  $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function(e) {
    var dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
    dropdown.find('ul').slideToggle('fast');

    $('.dropdown').not(dropdown).find('ul').slideUp('fast');

  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").slideUp('fast');

  });

  $('.multiSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var title = $(this).closest('.multiSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
      title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
      $('.multiSel').append(html);
      $(".hida").hide();
    } else {
      $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
      var ret = $(".hida");
      $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

    }
  });


});
```

Comment: This is like having waited for a bus for 5 years then suddenly 3 come at once!  Thanks @Colin0117.  Yes, it's effective.  Suddenly checkbox filters on datatables are no longer the mystery they once were.

Comment: Ha, I didn't realise this was an old one, just looked interesting :)