# Problems with the translation of datatables

Tags: javascript, html-table, datatables

I can't understand why I can't translate Datatables via the CDN. If I use a written dictionary directly in the code everything works but with the CDN I receive error.
I attach the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Table Filter</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS Datatables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.3/af-2.3.7/b-2.0.1/b-html5-2.0.1/b-print-2.0.1/cr-1.5.5/date-1.1.1/fc-4.0.1/fh-3.2.0/r-2.2.9/sb-1.3.0/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.css"/>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    
        .dataTables_length {
            margin: 15px;
        }
    
        .dataTables_filter {
            margin: 15px;
        }
    
        .dataTables_filter input {
            width: 350px;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
    
        th:hover {
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown-wrap {
            max-height: 180px;
            /* At most, around 3/4 visible items. */
            position: relative;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 15px;
            color: black;
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown,
        .cb-dropdown li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    
        /* For selected filter. */
        .active .cb-dropdown {
            background: rgb(255, 244, 92);
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown-wrap:hover .cb-dropdown {
            height: 250px;
            overflow: auto;
            transition: 0.2s height ease-in-out;
            background: #fff;
        }
    
        /* For selected items. */
        .cb-dropdown li.active {
            background: #ff0;
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown li label {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 19px;
            /* Match height of .cb-dropdown-wrap */
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown li label>input {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 16px;
        }
    
        .cb-dropdown li label>span {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            /* At least, width of the checkbox. */
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-align: left;
        }
    
        /* This fixes the vertical aligning of the sorting icon. */
        table.dataTable thead .sorting,
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
        table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
            background-position: 100% 10px;
        }
    
        .paginate_button {
            margin: 7px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    
        .paginate_button:hover {
            cursor: default;
        }
    
        thead {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
        }
    </style>

    <!-- JQuery  -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

    <!-- Javascripts Datatables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.11.3/af-2.3.7/b-2.0.1/b-html5-2.0.1/b-print-2.0.1/cr-1.5.5/date-1.1.1/fc-4.0.1/fh-3.2.0/r-2.2.9/sb-1.3.0/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <p style="text-align: center">
        This Fiddle was forked by <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/9217760/sally-cj">Sally</a>, for <a
            href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/49846701/9217760">this Stack Overflow question</a>. <small><a
                href="https://jsfiddle.net/jvretamero/bv6g0r64/">See the original Fiddle</a>.</small>
    </p>

    <hr />
    <div>
        <table id="example" class="display table table-primary table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-center text-uppercase">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th >Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th class="sum">Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>2010/12/22</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2010/11/14</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2011/06/07</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fiona Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>2010/03/11</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shou Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>2011/08/14</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michelle House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2011/06/02</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suki Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>2009/10/22</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/05/07</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2011/02/03</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2013/02/01</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/12/06</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2011/03/21</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lael Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2009/02/27</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2010/07/14</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shad Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/11/13</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="/jsMyTable.js"></script> -->

    <script>
        // This code has been beautified via http://jsbeautifier.org/ with 2 spaces indentation.
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function cbDropdown(column) {
                return $("<ul>", {
                    class: "cb-dropdown",
                }).appendTo(
                    $("<div>", {
                        class: "cb-dropdown-wrap",
                    }).appendTo(column)
                );
            }

            $("#example").DataTable({
                // This part doesn't work
                "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Italian.json"
                },
                //

                dom: "Qlfrtip",
                lengthMenu: [
                    [25, 50, 100, -1],
                    [25, 50, 100, "All"],
                ],
                sDom: '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>',

                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api()
                        .columns()
                        .every(function () {
                            var column = this;
                            var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header())).on(
                                "change",
                                ":checkbox",
                                function () {
                                    var active;
                                    var vals = $(":checked", ddmenu)
                                        .map(function (index, element) {
                                            active = true;
                                            return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
                                        })
                                        .toArray()
                                        .join("|");

                                    column
                                        .search(vals.length > 0 ? "^(" + vals + ")$" : "", true, false)
                                        .draw();

                                    // Highlight the current item if selected.
                                    if (this.checked) {
                                        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).closest("li").removeClass("active");
                                    }

                                    // Highlight the current filter if selected.
                                    var active2 = ddmenu.parent().is(".active");
                                    if (active && !active2) {
                                        ddmenu.parent().addClass("active");
                                    } else if (!active && active2) {
                                        ddmenu.parent().removeClass("active");
                                    }
                                }
                            );

                            column
                                .data()
                                .unique()
                                .sort()
                                .each(function (d, j) {
                                    var // wrapped
                                        $label = $("<label>"),
                                        $text = $("<span>", {
                                            text: d,
                                        }),
                                        $cb = $("<input>", {
                                            type: "checkbox",
                                            value: d,
                                        });

                                    $text.appendTo($label);
                                    $cb.appendTo($label);

                                    ddmenu.append($("<li>").append($label));
                                });
                        });
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The part that creates problems is this (located in the script tag before the closure of body) :

```
        // This part doesn't work
        "language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Italian.json"
        },
        //
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the protocol (`https:`) in that URL:

```js
"language": {
  "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Italian.json"
},
```

Protocol-relative URLs should generally be avoided these days. For some background, see [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/):

> Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn't have performance concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then always use the `https://` asset.

---

**Update**

Based on your MRE, you have the wrong set of resources (jQuery, Bootstrap, DataTables) in your page's `<head>` tag.

Look at your browser's console and you will see one or more errors - which prevent your DataTable from being created. You only see a basic HTML table.

For example, if you remove them all, and instead use the following very basic set of resources...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.3/datatables.min.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

...then you will see that your translations are working correctly. For example:

```
Vista da 1 a 8 di 8 elementi
```

But more than that, you will actually see the DataTable with its controls being displayed.

You will still need to do some more work, to provide *all* the resources you actually need for correct display and styling of all the features you need.

I recommend you visit the [official DataTables downloads](https://datatables.net/download/index) page and select all the options you want. That will generate what you need.

You may need to experiment a bit to get everything you need. If you get stuck with that process, you can ask a new question, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the support! Is it Ok for you as minimal reproducible example? https://jsbin.com/xipegaf/edit?html,output

Comment: Yes - thanks - that MRE helps. It's a problem with the resources provided in the page head. I have added some notes to my answer.